# What does the "left to" in this sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's the meaning of the sentence I highlighted below? Does it mean that the code should be both correct and shared?

> [...] The read-only nature of shared code should not be ***left to*** the correctness of the code; the operating system should enforce this property.

---

[image: left_to]

Comment: Please replace the screen shoot with text.

Comment: It is not clear how **correctness** can enforce read-only. I would expect to find **should not be left to the code itself**. Maybe they mean to say "left to the code's re-entrant nature"?

Comment: That's just it, @Tᴚoɯɐuo.  The code's correctness can *suggest* that it not be altered, but it can't enforce it.  We don't want to rely on an "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" policy to keep the shared code intact.  Not every developer will recognize an ain't-broke status correctly.

Comment: @Gary Botnovcan: I do understand the concept. My criticism is of the language. I don't see how **correctness** can *suggest* anything either, except perhaps that there's no *good reason* to alter it.  The phrase **left to ... correctness** makes **correctness** an agent of some kind, which it ain't.  That's very elliptical writing.

Comment: Ah, that's where we see things differently?  I have no problem with abstract, impersonal, or even rhetorical agents.  "Justice demands . . . ," "Propriety requires . . . ," "The evidence suggests . . . ." -- saying that the code's correctness can't produce an effect seems an extraordinary claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you know the meaning of

> The read-only nature of shared code

The article means, this thing should be assure by operating system rather than correctness of the code.

> The read-only ... should not be left to the correctness ... to ensure.

Other similar expresstion,

> The safety of Chinese citizens should not be left to American troops.

It implies the safety of Chinese citizens should be left to Chinese troops (or other things).